# Checking two chars/strings using String.contains

Tags: string, char, contains

Is it possible to check two chars at once when using String.contains?

I am speaking of something like this:

```
if (String.contains("@" && ".com"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This is an E-mail Address!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
```

I have tried doing it this way, However with no success and looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String#contains() like this in your code:

```
  if ((String.contains("@")) && (String.contains(".com")))
    {

    }
```

Comment: Foolish me, there we go! Thank you :)